# Resolve domain upon environment

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-proxy

I am using dnsmasq to resolve specific sites while doing some stress tasks, but since we have at least 3 environments per site I have to constantly update the target IP.
These sites are behind a reverse proxy, so I need to target specific IP with the corresponding domain...if not I would have set 3 environments with their own ip as site1.test, site1.stage & site1.live.
Is there any way I could browse site1.test but really trying to reach site1.com with IP of site1.test? By dnsmasq I accomplish the IP resolution.

If question is a bit confusing let me know.

Thanks!